# ERROR : CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Hy Guys, I am Beginner Android Developer. I need your help. i want to insert data into 2 tables of sqlite tblorder, and orderdtl. on orderdtl i have to insert data from multiple item from listview. i try to toast all variable that i want to inserted. their all appears. but when i try to save it. i get those error.
this is my DBDataSource.java

```
public order createorder(String orderid, String notes, long outletid) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBHelper.ORDER_ID, orderid); // inserting a string
    values.put(DBHelper.NOTES, notes); // inserting an int
    values.put(DBHelper.OUTLET_ID, outletid); // inserting an int

    long insertId = database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_ORDER, null,
            values);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_ORDER,
            allorder, DBHelper.ORDER_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
            null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        order neworder = cursorToorder(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return neworder;}
 private order cursorToorder(Cursor cursor) {
    order order = new order();
    order.setorderid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ORDER_ID)));
    order.setorderdate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ORDER_DATE)));
    order.setnotes(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NOTES)));
    order.setoutletid(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.OUTLET_ID)));
    return order;
    }
```

The error refer to this code

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_ORDER,
            allorder, DBHelper.ORDER_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
            null, null, null);
```

And this code

```
order.setorderid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ORDER_ID)));
```

orderid is string, i try to get from yyyyMMddHHmmss.this is the code:

```
    private String orderid(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
```

}
I would be very grateful for any help that you give.Thank You.

Comment: In BackupDatastore, why does `getPlayer_8()` return `this._Player_1`? Shouldn't it be `this._Player_8`?

Comment: That was a mistake when I typed up the thread. It actually returns this._Player_8. Still get the error described above

Comment: Does the "clean installation" mean that you've uninstalled the app and then installed it again?

Comment: Yes, I went to application manager cleared all app data. Then uninstalled app. Then reinstalled it. Still issue exists

Comment: at which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: I've added the logcat file

Comment: It's quite possible that Android is creating a default database before  your code executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query didn't match any rows. Check the result of `moveToFirst()` to see whether the operation succeeded and only then access cursor data.

Example:

```
order neworder = null;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    order neworder = cursorToorder(cursor);
}
cursor.close();
return neworder;
```

The `insertId` you get from `insert()` is the sqlite row id for the row. It's likely not the same as `ORDER_ID`. To make a column an alias for rowid, declare it as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: you right, i forget to change those part. primary key should be autoincrement to use those code. you remember me.thanks alto

Answer (score 1):

The error I see in logcat is not about _Player_8, but about the unknown column "KEY_Team_Name"

The problem is in your activity, the line prior to the last one:

```
String EntryA =String.valueOf( db.getentry("Ravirrrr", "KEY_Team_Name"));
```

It should be:

```
String EntryA =String.valueOf( db.getentry("Ravirrrr", DatabaseHandler.KEY_Team_Name));
```

And the DatabaseHandler should have all column names public, as the getentry method requires a column name.

Edit: adding an answer to the question in the comments below.
After calling db.query, you should check if you got something by calling Cursor.isAfterLast(). If true, the select returned an empty result set.
In your example, you WILL get an empty result set as the code creates an entry with "Ravi" as the team name, then asks for a team named "Ravirrrr".

Comment: Now I'm getting the error: 

CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0